# Visual Studio 2013 Debug keyboard shortcuts are not working

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, breakpoints

I just got a new computer with Windows 8 and installed Visual Studio 2013 on it and now I have an issue with debugger shortcuts - I run application in a debug mode and it breaks at the first break point but when I try going further line by line, F10 does not work from the keyboard - only VS Debug menu. Anything I am missing?

P.S. The issue was the function key. It needs to be turned on in order to use F keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my issue and wanted to post an answer in case anyone is looking for it. Enabling function key does not require any complicated solution, it can be enabled by changing settings in:

Control Panel ->  Hardware and Sound (Category) -> Windows Mobility Center -> Adjust Commonly Used Mobility Settings

Look Under Function Key Behavior and change the dropdown value to "Function Key" to enable Fn key.

To disable it, select "Multimedia Key"

See: http://elena-sqldba.blogspot.com/2015/05/how-to-enable-function-key-on-windows.html

Answer (score 6):

On Lenovo laptops, there is a shortcut to disable the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key automatically running the default Windows shortcuts.
Hit the <kbd>Fn</kbd>  key and the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key at the same time to toggle the "*Hot Key*" default.

Hope this works for other Laptop brands since this is an easy shortcut for newer Lenovo laptops.

Comment: Worked for me too dude.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the instruction here, though it talks about visual studio 2010 it should help you to analyze the problem. it may be solved with the steps described there and if not, please let me know...

[Why does F10 (step over) in Visual Studio 2010 not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427173/why-does-f10-step-over-in-visual-studio-2010-not-work)

**Update** Adding the answer from the source in case the link will be removed:

> In the Options.Keyboard page, please select "Debug.StepOver" from the command listbox, and then put focus to the "Press shortcut keys" textbox and press F10, click Assign button to re-assign shortcut, does it work?
>
> You can also try to run Visual Studio under safe mode, which will
>   prevents all third-party VSPackages from loading when Visual Studio
>   starts; if the issue disappear under safe mode, you may consider
>   checking your installed add-ons or VSPackages.
>
> Second, to log all activity of Visual Studio to a log file for further
>   troubleshooting, please use the /Log switch, and post the log file
>   content here, so we can do more investigation on it.
>
> If this feature works well before, and suddenly behave abnormally, it
>   usually indicate that some files or configurations of Visual Studio
>   installation is corrupted or missed, you can:
>
> Restores Visual Studio default settings by using "Devenv.exe
>   /ResetSettings" command. Please backup your settings before restore to
>   default settings.
>
> Repair/reinstall Visual Studio;
>
> To repair Visual Studio In the Add or Remove Programs dialog box,
>   select Visual Studio then click Change/Remove.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunatelly it did not help. VS ignores keyboard shortcuts completely

Comment: This should probably have been a dupe flag, not an answer.

Comment: I found that my step over/shortcut key wasn't working because it was hitting a flag that I forgot about and it was causing it to exit the loop instead of stepping in.

Answer (score 1):

Also check 3rd party software.  In my case I had Camtasia Recorder open and minimized, which apparently intercepts the F10 input (thanks, TechSmith)

Comment: Thanks god. It wasn't exactly Camtasia Recorder, it was other recording software, but still, I wouldn't figure it out without your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My solution was a bit different and can apply to any key. My F10 key was not working. After unplugging the keyboard and plugging it back in did not fix the problem, I twisted the keyboard like an ice cube tray and the F10 key started working again.